# What is the regex to match an exact alphanumeric 18 character string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to write a regex pattern which will match the exact alphanumeric (space and special characters are not allowed) string with the length of 18 characters.

**Examples:**

1) `axspa6577dRTu8Hjg2` - This should match

2) `axspa6577drtu8hjg2` - This should match

3) `6577daxspaRtU8hJG2` - This should match

4) `657712873456901338` - This should not match

5) `sedrfutklenfgoemsl` - This should not match

6) `ASDEFRTGJUNLEOFNVY` - This should not match

7) `AS34df67-_%&*()@#!` - This should not match

I tried below one, but it doesn't work for me.

```
^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{18})$
```

It matches all the special characters along with the alphanumeric string.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how form a good question. A 5 minute search tells me ([0-z]{18}) should work.

Comment: do you need exactly single regexp?

Comment: @Onots that isn't that he wants

Comment: @Onots: The 4th, 5th & 6th examples will fail in this case.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ: Yes, I need exactly single regexp.

Comment: I misread the question. You are right, the regex i suggested does not meet the requirementd. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex uses positive look ahead to match:

```
(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{18}
```

It matches any group contains at least one letter, at least one number, consists of only letters and numbers and is exactly 18 characters long.

Comment: Yes.. This is working absolutely fine.. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `regexp` to match a border between letter and digits, and strikt match for both letters and digits in the other places in a string:

```
/^[\da-zA-Z]*([\d][a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][0-9])[\da-zA-Z]*$/
```

or

```
/^[[:alnum:]]*([\d][[:alpha:]]|[[:alpha:]][0-9])[[:alnum:]]*$/
```

Comment: This will allow underscore ( _ ) as well.. which is not expected.